# IE login automation - How to press submit button?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, email, authentication

I am trying to log into an email account using IE as a browser, this is all to be automated using excels VBA environment, so far I have the following:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub login()
    Const cURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"
    Const cUsername = "XXXX"    'REPLACE XXXX WITH YOUR USER NAME
    Const cPassword = "YYYY"    'REPLACE YYYY WITH YOUR PASSWORD

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
    Dim UserNameInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim SignInButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
    Dim HTMLelement As IHTMLElement

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate cURL

    'Wait for initial page to load
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Set doc = IE.Document

    'Get the only form on the page
    Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)

    'Get the User Name textbox and populate it
    Set UserNameInputBox = LoginForm.elements("cred_userid_inputtext")
    UserNameInputBox.Value = cUsername

    'Get the password textbox and populate it
    Set PasswordInputBox = LoginForm.elements("cred_password_inputtext")
    PasswordInputBox.Value = cPassword

    'Get the form input button and click it
    Set SignInButton = LoginForm.elements("cred_sign_in_button")
    SignInButton.Click

    'Wait for the new page to load
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Debug.Print "Current URL: " & IE.LocationURL

End Sub
```

Using this code, the username and password enter fine but the problem occurs when I try to press the "submit" button, I get a runtime error and dont know why, I think it may be a javascript object however, cannot figure out how to get VBA to press it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use `LoginForm.Submit`

Comment: can you provide relevant HTML code for the submit button?  And what  run-time error is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the LoginForm item is a true html 'form' element, then it should have a submit method. In which case `LoginForm.Submit` would do the trick

Comment: Thanks, I am now in. Do you have any idea how to create a new email message within the microsoft 365 using vba?

Comment: I do - but that would need to be posted as a separate question as it's not really relevant to this thread. :)

Comment: I have created the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305885/press-new-mail-button-in-microsoft-365-email-using-vba?noredirect=1#comment43074433_27305885 your help with this is greatly appreciated!